# About pointers to structs and how they works

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree, nodes

i have this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    struct node* next;
    int data;
}NODE;
NODE* makeNode (int x){
    NODE* new;
    new = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new -> data = x;
    new -> next= NULL;
    return new;
}
typedef NODE* linkedlist;
void insertnode (NODE** node, int x){
    if(!(*node))
        *node=makeNode(x);
    else
        insertnode(&((*node)->next), x);
}
void deletenode(NODE** node){

    (*node)=NULL;
    free (*node);
}
int main()
{
    NODE* node;
    linkedlist mylist;
    mylist=NULL;
    insertnode(&mylist, 3); //insert a node
    insertnode(&mylist, 4);
    node = mylist->next; //
    deletenode(&(mylist->next));
    printf("\n%d\n",node->data); // prints 4
    return 0;
}
```

I was studyng binary search trees and when i arrive to the deletion part i started to doubt about how pointers works in memory and my world got collapsed.

I will use this linked list code instead the BST code because is more easy to me for explain my doubts.

Well, if i do this `node=NULL;` mylist will still exist because node is a copy of the pointer to mylist, but when i do this:

```
free(node->next);
node->next=NULL;
```

mylist->next will no longer exist because `node->next` is the original pointer of that next node.

So in the code i did a copy of `mylist->next` pointer in `node`

```
node = mylist->next;
```

i assume this is what happen:

> mylist-------------->[|data|next|]->[|data|next|]<------------------node;

Then i delete the original node. But when i print `node->date` for my surprise the program prints 4.

I understand thats the pointers are variables that hold a memory location. But i can't get why `node->data;` still exist if i'd set free the node and set it `NULL;` just affected the pointer and not the memory?

when i free and NULL a pointer what happens with the memory blocks what that pointer holds?

My problems is with the pointers to structs, and how they work with the memory allocated pointed by them.

I hope i make me understand, my english is't so good.

Comment: Setting the value to NULL before you free it is a bad idea.  You are always calling free(NULL), and not actually freeing anything.  Instead of `*node = NULL; free(*node)`, try `free(*node); *node = NULL;`

Comment: Your `deletenode` function does not do the right thing; it needs to update the previous node's `next` too (which is difficult with your current setup)

Comment: @MattMcNabb yeah i know, i tip this code just for expose my doubt and it's not functional. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer points to a memory location.

After `free()` you are giving back the allocated memory back to OS.

Accessing this memory is UB(Undefined behavior)

So you might see expected result but since you have UB this is not guaranteed at all time.

In you case let's say you free the memory the pointer mylist->next is pointing to.

```
free(mylist->next)
mylist->next = NULL;
```

Now the memory held by the pointer `mylist->next` is returned back to OS. Since this memory is available to the OS it can do anything with it. In your case it now writing anytihng to this location and retaining what is there before the `free()` so you are getting back `4` but if this memory was used to allocate to someother purpose then you might have not got what you expected.

So basically accessing the memory which is freed leads to UB

Comment: so don't matters if set NULL the pointer, the memory gonna still retaining what was there, but is gonna be free anyways? Ok, i get it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing memory after freeing invokes undefined behavior.
Some possible outcomes are:

- You may get the data that was previously lodged at that address.
- You may get zero or some other value
- Program may crash

But this list is not comprehensive, some else may also happen.

Takeaway is, never access a data from memory location that is freed.